# GITLAB web IDE change default option - create a new branch

Tags: gitlab, branch, commit, git-branch, git-commit

I'm using GitLab web IDE, but every time I want to commit my changes the default option is: "Create a new branch", with "Start new merge request" option checked.
I want to push on develop branch, then I switch manually every time to develop... but this boring :(

But before it was automatically "Commit to develop branch".

Is there a solution to restore the previous configuration? thx

Comment: Nobody looks to understand why this change appeared... Does anybody know how to change that??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the Web IDE tab is open then the default option for the submit is to create a new branch. But if I choose the other option, then the next commits will keep my selection as the default one.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set develop as the default branch. The default branch is the branch that changes will automatically be merged into and it's the branch that automatically opens when visiting the GitLab web interface.

These are the steps:

1. Choose in the leftside menue bar "Settings > Repository > Default Branch"
2. Determine your default branch

Comment: My default branch is already develop, and, as described in the subject, using the web IDE the default option during the commit (and automatic push) is "Create a new branch" with the name "username-develop-patch-number"